# Gnome indicator applet not showing same items on two computers

Tags: indicator, gnome-panel

I have one computer running Lucid and another one that I recently upgraded to Maverick. Up until today, I was using AWN with Maverick, including their custom indicator applets. I've decided to switch back to the default gnome panels with dockbarx, but when I add the indicator applet to my panel, it's not displaying the same items as the applet on my Lucid machine. In particular, the network and Dropbox icons are not displaying.

When I look at the About entry for the apps, Lucid shows version 0.3.7, whereas Maverick shows 0.4.6. Did they really remove the network information from the applet in Maverick, or do I need to do something to enable it? My network is very definitely connected, as I still have AWN running and can see the icon there.

(A second question, although not particularly important: the applet doesn't inherit the transparency of the panel it's living on - any way to change that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add "systray" to the gnome-panel? The network-manager should be displayed then.

The systray-applet can only be started once, so if it runs with awn, it would not be displayed in the gnome-panel. It will be displayed on that panel you started first.

Comment: As it turned out, for whatever reason indicator-network was uninstalled when upgrading to Maverick. systray is not an option in my add to panel applets list. Where do I get it?

Comment: If you type "nm-applet" in a terminal, it should answer, that it is still running and cannot be started again. If not, you have to install "network-manager" and "network-manager-gnome" with Synaptic for example. The next thing is to add the "Notifikation Area" to your panel (see next answer from Roland Taylor). Another problem maybe that awn has allready startet "systray". Remove "systray"-applet from awn-panel if it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Only one notification area can be displayed at a time. That means that because you have a notification area in AWN, the notification items will not show up in the panel. To get the icon into your panel, remove the notification area applet from AWN.

Answer (score 0):

Add the notification area to your panel.
[image]

The answer to your second question is complicated: it depends on the theme as well.

Comment: notification area is already on my panel...

Comment: do you have nm-applet installed?